# Iteratively assign variable names for calculations done on list within a list in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested-lists

I have been having an issue in R studio for a while now and I would like to preface that I am still fairly new to R and still don't know all the "fastest" methods of doings things but any help and patience would be awesome.

I am a researcher having to calculate skill scores for weather models at different weather stations and have thousands of data points to iterate over and I figured the easiest method to do this was read in the files and store each file as a separate list in a list.

After doing this I would, loop over each list in the lists, and calculate different error scores (normal error, RMSE, etc...) saving me from having to copy and paste about 121 different loops.
This method of doing things is clearly A) not a good method, or B) I do not have a firm grasp on the best way of doing this.

So, below is an quick example:

```
# The weather model forecasts
model1 <- c(1:15)
model2 <- c(1:15)
model3 <- c(1:15)

# What actually happened (verification/measured values)
verification_model1 <- c(1:15)
verification_model2 <- c(1:15)
verification_model3 <- c(1:15)

# List of lists containging total model data
totalmodeldata <- list(model1,model2,model3)
totalverificationdata <-list(verification_model1,verification_model2,verification_model3)

# Calculate normal error
for (val in totalmodeldata){
  for (ob in totalverificationdata){
    uniquevarname <- val - ob # here is the issue!
  }
}
```

So here is my one problem to make this a simple Q/A...

1. Is there a simple method to assigning unique variable names for these individual lists within a list calculations? Because as it stands now, the code does what it's supposed to do with error calculations but only stores the last list it calculates (model3.

Ideally it would do something where it calculates normal error for model1 VS. verification_model1 assigns data to a variable then moves to the second lists and so on so that I have normal error for model1, model2, and model3.

UPDATE:
Okay we are getting somewhere. This is the output I would like...
After declaring the model data (model1..2..3, etc.) and verification data (verifcation_model1..2..3,etc.) into the "total" lists, a for loop or similar function would loop through and do the below  subtraction to EACH model and verification data list:

```
unqiue_var_error1 <- model1 - verification_model1
unqiue_var_error2 <- model2 - verification_model2
unqiue_var_error3 <- model3 - verification_model3
```

The output/stored data would look like a simple vector of data for each model... Here is an actual output of normal error from my work:

```
> head(model1,n = 15L)
 [1] -6  0  1  0 -4 -2  2  0 -3 -2 -3 -5 -5 -5 -5
```

That way, once that loop is done I would have normal error for each model.

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to help you if you can (a) reduce your code to a concise, simple, reproducible example, and (b) provide exact expected output.  For (a), it doesn't even need to be your actual use case, variable names, etc, just something that isolates the problem you're having and makes it easier to inspect and reason about.  Right now, your post has a lot of code that isn't germane to reproducing the core issue.  Re (b), showing current output vs expected output, even if it's truncated to just show the first result or two, makes it easy to verify whether solutions are appropriate.

Comment: Hi @andrew_reece, I will update the code, thanks for replying!

Comment: @andrew_reece, I have updated the code. Let me know if that is more understandable. I have generalized a hefty amount.

Comment: Do you mean to nest the for loops? It doesn't make sense to me given the you want to apply a subtraction. If you're ok using the `purrr` package, you can do `purrr::map2(totalmodeldata, totalverificationdata, ~ .x - .y)`

Comment: Much easier to work with, thanks.  Note that you have `verification_model1` listed twice in `totalverificationdata`.

Comment: Re @Phil's question, it would help if you can provide expected output.  That will clarify if you really want to get a difference score between one value in `totalmodeldata` and _every_ value in `totalverificationdata`.  For example, do you really want the difference between a value in `model1` and every value in `verification_model1/2/3`?  That's what your current code will compute.

Comment: @Phil, It appears that purr is not compatible with 4.0.2 and am not familiar with that package. Would that function work do the simple subtraction for each list within my "totals" lists? Thanks.

Comment: @andrew_reece, Did not mean to put `verification_model1` twice. Was supposed to be `verification_model3`. I have made an update section of the type of output i would like. To clarify I want the difference of model1 to verification1, model2 to verification2 and so on. Not model1 to all verification data. I have tried to simplify that in the update. Thanks for all yalls help.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  In that case, I'd recommend removing the nested for loop you have in your post.  You can verify with a simple test that this will produce many more comparisons than your desired output.  (Also, please update the `verification_model1` typo.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using a nested [`purrr::map2`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html).
(You don't really need the nested mapping, it just allows for wrapping the results in a single data frame.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

map2_df(totalmodeldata, totalverificationdata,
     function(model, verify) {
       map2_dbl(model, verify, ~.x - .y)
     }
)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   model1 model2 model3
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -1.22  -0.611 -1.50 
 2  1.82   0.911  1.71 
 3  3.06   1.53   3.84 
 4 -1.40  -0.700 -1.37 
 5 -1.33  -0.665 -1.27 
 6  1.57   0.787  2.43 
 7  0.252  0.126  0.482
 8  1.77   0.886  1.14 
 9 -0.200 -0.100 -0.543
10  0.642  0.321  0.419
```

Data:

```r
# added randomness to avoid having all zeros show up in diff scores

# The weather model forecasts
set.seed(123)
n <- 10
model1 <- rnorm(n)
model2 <- model1 * .5
model3 <- model1 * 1.5

# What actually happened (verification/measured values)
set.seed(234)
verification_model1 <- rnorm(n)
verification_model2 <- verification_model1 * .5
verification_model3 <- verification_model1 * 1.5

# List of lists containging total model data
totalmodeldata <- 
  list(model1, model2, model3) %>% set_names('model1', 'model2', 'model3')

totalverificationdata <-
  list(verification_model1, verification_model2, verification_model1) %>% 
  set_names('ver_model1', 'ver_model2', 'ver_model3')
```

Note: The `purrr` package is a tidyverse take on the base R `apply` family functions (and per OP comment, it is compatible with R >= 3.2).

Comment: This is fantastic! This solution is just what I need.
My only issue that is left is with each model the sizes differ. That being said I have implemented your solution into my work and tested it on my model1 and verification_model1 and get an error for differing sizes. is there a work around? Here is the output:
`Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 994: Column `KGRR`.
* Size 1012: Column `KGFL`.
* Size 1025: Column `PAJN`.
* Size 1041: Column `KMAF`.
* Size 1062: Column `KMDL`.
ℹ … and 1 more problem.`

Comment: and this is the function that throws the error:
`GFSmaxT_Norm_Error <- map2_df(GFSmaxT, verifmaxT,
                    function(model, verify) {
                      map2_dbl(model, verify, ~.x - .y)
                    }
)`
`GFSmaxT` represents `model1` and `verifmaxT` represents `verification_model1`

Comment: that means you don't have the same number of values in your `model` and `verify` sets.  i'm not sure what that could mean, as your original post suggested you wanted to compare a specific `model` value against its corresponding element in `verify`.  but i see you have `tibble`s, which is also different than your original specs, where you talked about using lists.  the error you showed has at least 5 columns in your data frame.  seems like you might need to narrow down whatever is in your tibble to just the `model` and `verify` vectors.